# What "Tag Length" should be used for the EAX MAC?

Tags: modes-of-operation, mac, authenticated-encryption, collision-resistance, eax

Since EAX is very flexible with regard to the length of the calculated MAC (what they call "tag" is the MAC value right?), and the [EAX paper](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/eax.html) as well as other documentations carefully avoid suggesting any value for the length of the MAC, is there anything to take into consideration before setting for a value?

Is the length just "proportional" with collision resistance or are there also other more subtle consequences depending on the MAC length?

Answer (score 3):

While the EAX mode permits truncating the tag to any length $\tau$ between 0 and $n$ bits, where $n$ is the block size of the underlying block cipher, this should only be taken as a statement that truncating the tag in EAX mode does not introduce any security issues beyond the obvious (an attacker only needs $2^\tau$ attempts to froge a $\tau$-bit tag by brute force).  Still, in the absence of a particular space or bandwidth constraint that would *require* a shorter tag, I see no reason not to use a full-length tag ($\tau = n$).

(I suspect the main reason for introducing a variable tag length into EAX was because CCM had one; see the table in figure 4 of the EAX paper you cited.  EAX was designed as a replacement for CCM, and so one of the main design goals was to be able to do anything CCM did, only better.  If EAX had been specified with a fixed tag length, someone might have cited that "missing feature" as a reason to use CCM over EAX.)